# Flutter - New Project - able to run flutter app on iPhone but not able to run ios app on simulator iPhone 15 Pro Max

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, simulator

Error (Xcode): Target debug_unpack_ios failed: Exception: Binary /Users/fathom/Documents/Documents/Flutter/projects_bitbucket/flashwave/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flutter.framework/Flutter does not exist, cannot thin

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 15 Pro Max.

***Xcode - Version 15.0.1 (15A507)***

Answer (score 0):

You have to reinstall flutter.
I had the same issue after the macOS update.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I update flutter version and dart version after the macOS update, now its working fine.